# Migrating large CVS repository to SVN

Tags: svn, migration, cvs2svn

I have a large CVS repository module (~2.2GB of CVS and has 10 years of active development).  I'm attempting to migrate it to SVN in order to host it on Google Code, which has about 1GB limit.

Is there a way to do a partial migration, where I only migrate the last year worth of changes only?  cvs2svn and cvs2ps in the documentation discuss partial migration by prune folders not by pruning history.

Comment: no, don't migrate to svn.  If you're going to migrate, make the jump to something truly modern, like git. :P  git doesn't do partial history, but it does have _very_ efficient delta compression, and doesn't need to keep uncompressed copies of files lying around (in your working directory or in the repo).

Comment: @Peter, Thanks.  I use git and hg for all my other projects!

Comment: @PeterCordes, git is a powerfull version control system, however some tools like MyEclipse doesn't support it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cvs2svn does not have a feature to discard part of the CVS history.  But you can convert the whole history then use "svnadmin dump" and "svnadmin load" to discard part of the repository after the conversion:

```
svnadmin dump -r R:HEAD /path/to/full/repo | svnadmin load /path/to/abbreviated/repo
```

where "R" is the SVN revision number of the first revision you would like to retain.

But instead of throwing away history that might someday be missed, see if you can get Google to [raise the limits for your project](http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/FAQ#Hosted_Tools):

> There are disk-space quota limits for both issue tracker attachments and total Subversion repository size, along
>   with a limit on how many total projects you are able to create. If you hit these limits, please contact us via our
>   Google Group or email google-code-hosting@googlegroups.com directly to discuss the situation.